# Preview before Video creation

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avfoundation

I am creating an application that takes photos and videos as input and create the final video containing the added contents with a audio. 
I have an array of images and videos. I want to create preview player to play the images and videos stored in array in the order they were added before finally saving the video.
Any help is welcomed....